# react native webview not loading dynamic content

Tags: react-native

****React native****
I am trying to implement react native WebView component in my application, but the web
view is not loading dynamic URL its showing the below output.

```
               import React, {Component} from 'react';
               import {View} from 'react-native';
               import {WebView} from 'react-native-WebView';
            
            export default class App extends Component {
              render() {
                return (

                  <WebView
                   source={{uri:'www.amazon.com'}}
                   
                  />
                );
              }
            }
    



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSyni.png
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot https for url link :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
      }}>
      <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        source={{ uri: 'https://www.amazon.com/' }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

https://snack.expo.dev/T80XSC2XW

Comment: i modified code like that but i'm still facing the same issue .i'm using react native cli not expo.could you please help me